# Switch integral and sum

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the measure space $([0,1), \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}, \lambda)$ and the function (for $n \geq 1$ and $x \in [0,1)$):

$u_{n}=nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^{n}$

I have shown that $u_{n} \in \mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1),\lambda)$ and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{[0,1)}u_{n}d\lambda(x)=0$.

I now wish to:

a) Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x)$

b) Argue that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x) \in \mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1),\lambda)$

c) Find $\int_{[0,1)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}d\lambda(x)$

I have done the following:

a)

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x) =$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^{n} = $

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n} = $

$\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}} - \frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)^{2}} =$

$\frac{1-x(x-2)}{(x-1)^{2}}$

b)

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x) = \frac{1-x(x-2)}{(x-1)^{2}}$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ then it is measurable and Riemann integrable. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}(x) \in \mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1),\lambda)$.

c)

$\int_{[0,1)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}d\lambda(x) =$

$\int_{[0,1)} \frac{1-x(x-2)}{(x-1)^{2}} d\lambda(x) =$

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x(x-2)}{(x-1)^{2}}(x) =$

The last definite integral diverges.

Are a), b) and c) correct?

Comment: As to (a): $\sum_1^\infty nx^{n-1} = \left(\sum_0^\infty x^n\right)' = \left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)' = \frac 1{(1-x)^2}$ and $\sum_1^\infty (n+1)x^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^{n-1} = -1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac 1{(1-x)^2}-1$. Or just$$\sum_1^\infty u_n = \sum_1^\infty nx^{n-1} - \sum_1^\infty (n+1)x^n = \sum_1^\infty nx^{n-1} - \sum_2^\infty nx^{n-1} = 1.$$